# Получение непустых записей из массива mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Имеется запись типа:

```
{
    "_id" : "9a4b7791-c0ff-11e5-84d2-0cc47a13d3da",
    "dateEdit" : "2019-07-08 14:39:38",
    "categoriesID" : {
        "categoryId" : [ 
            {
                "text" : "db710657-ba27-4245-9c12-5ab37f50a962"
            }
        ]
    },
    "model" : "Glossa Коробка накладного монтажа, перламутр",
    "producer" : "Schneider Electric",
    "vendorCode" : "GSL000600",
    "series" : "GLOSSA",
    "discountCode" : "b530121c-5b1d-11e3-8764-00259096c80e",
    "mainImage" : "",
    "images" : {
        "image" : []
    },
    "stepCount" : "1",
    "params" : {
        "param" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Тип товара",
                "id" : "16b8f0b6-d400-4c5c-b73a-a8c058ddb0bd",
                "value" : "Коробка открытого монтажа 1-местная"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Производитель",
                "id" : "3846d1fd-f013-426f-9ba3-e9a662844c01",
                "value" : "Schneider Electric"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Оттенок",
                "id" : "087deb15-167d-4fac-8a60-7db55bbf4f95",
                "value" : "перламутр"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Цвет",
                "id" : "c57a5015-4e65-4b1c-9639-307fb900c9c6",
                "value" : "Белый"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Ед. измерения",
                "id" : "8a2d9a2c-9c01-4418-9c3f-17b4daae522c",
                "value" : "шт"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Страна",
                "id" : "7dfccb66-5668-4845-84cd-7dd0e9ee8d53",
                "value" : "Россия"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Материал",
                "id" : "93147b14-c5e4-463d-893f-a1be12b395ad",
                "value" : "термопласт"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Степень защиты",
                "id" : "0038e701-5614-4ee5-b0f4-cb7cc7b4e5da",
                "value" : "IP20"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Способ монтажа",
                "id" : "fe62943a-c193-4188-b3a8-9fc454048db2",
                "value" : "открытый"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Количество постов",
                "id" : "bd1a0913-18a7-44c0-b442-e8741623a384",
                "value" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Стиль",
                "id" : "7d6efdf6-7ed2-4d88-b7b3-29ead2898310",
                "value" : "Нейтральный"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Ценовая принадлежность",
                "id" : "4051ef1c-5bd2-4933-be0d-073ba737519b",
                "value" : "Эконом"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Артикул",
                "id" : "bitrix-q7sgmzei-4rcp-mt1a-jqig-jfwpei6v4u5j",
                "value" : "SCGSL000600"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Необходимо подсчитать количество пустых значений params.param.value где params.param.name Артикул
Попробовал сделать следующим образом:

```
db.getCollection('Offers').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                description: { $ifNull: [ "$params.param.value", "Unspecified" ] }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "params.param": {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$params.param",
                        as: "param",
                        cond: { 
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                    "$$param.name",
                                    "Артикул"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                    "$$param.value",
                                    "Unspecified"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $count: "result"
        }
    ]
)
```

Но не помогло, все равно result = количеству всех записей в базе.

Также попробовал сделать:

```
db.getCollection('Offers').aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            "params.param": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$params.param",
                    as: "param",
                    cond: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $ifNull: [
                                        "$$param.value",
                                        "Exp"
                                    ]
                                },
                                { $eq: [
                                        "$$param.name",
                                        "Артикул"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
         $project: {
            "params.param": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$params.param",
                    as: "param",
                    cond: {
                        $ne: ["$$param", null] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
     },
     {
        $count: "res"
     }
])
```

Выдает ошибку времени выполнения.
Данный кусок кода:

```
{
             $project: {
                "params.param": {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$params.param",
                        as: "param",
                        cond: {
                            $ne: ["$$param", null] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
         }
```

Вставил в расчёте на то, что будут убраны записи типа (это результат, который возвращает предыдущий блок $project в совокупности с $filter)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а такие записи соответственно будут считаться(тоже результат который возвращает вышестоящий блок $project в совокупности с $filter)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст запроса получился следующим:

```
db.getCollection('Offers').aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            "params.param": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$params.param",
                    as: "param",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $ifNull: [
                                    "$$param.value",
                                    "Exp"
                                ]
                            },
                            { $eq: [
                                "$$param.name",
                                "Артикул"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "params.param": {$eq: []}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

В первом блоке проверяется массив params.param на то, что его value не null. Также на данном этапе отбрасываются записи, в которых нет Артикула совсем.
Корректные записи после данного этапа будут выводиться следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некорректные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого блока при помощи match отбираем пустые(или наоборот непустые params.param в зависимости от того, что необходимо).
И, в заключительном блоке, просто указываем, что необходимо вывести _id этих записей